# Replace string after semicolon

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file `filtered_content` with the following content:

```
ip-172-31-42324-162.sa-east-1.compute.internal;2021-06-26T05:07:30Z
ip-172-31-42324-162.sa-east-1.compute.internal;2021-10-12T05:07:30Z
ip-172-31-4234-163.sa-east-1.compute.internal;2021-03-02T05:07:30Z
ip-172-31-4234-163.sa-east-1.compute.internal;2021-05-26T05:07:30Z
```

and another file `converted_data` with content:

```
1624684050
1634015250
1614661650
1622005650
```

I want to replace strings after semicolon in `filtered_content` with content of `converted_data` like this:

```
ip-172-31-42324-162.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1624684050
ip-172-31-42324-162.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1634015250
ip-172-31-4234-163.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1614661650
ip-172-31-4234-163.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1622005650
```

I tried something like this, but doesn't work.

```
data=$(cat /tmp/converted_data)
cat /tmp/filtered_content | sed 's/;.*//' | sed 's/.${data};//'
```

Comment: Maybe what you really want is convert the readable to date to UNIX timestamp instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another awk, using `getline` to read from `converted_data`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} getline $NF <"converted_data"' filtered_content
```

Output:

```
ip-172-31-42324-162.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1624684050
ip-172-31-42324-162.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1634015250
ip-172-31-4234-163.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1614661650
ip-172-31-4234-163.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1622005650
```

If `converted_data` has less lines than `filtered_content`, `getline` returns 0 and the line from `filtered_content` won't get printed. If `converted_data` does not exist, -1 is returned and the line `filtered_content` is output as-is.

Answer (score 6):

You may consider this `awk` solution:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR==FNR {arr[FNR]=$1; next} {$2 = arr[FNR]} 1' converted_data filtered_content

ip-172-31-42324-162.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1624684050
ip-172-31-42324-162.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1634015250
ip-172-31-4234-163.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1614661650
ip-172-31-4234-163.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1622005650
```

A more readable form:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
NR == FNR {
   arr[FNR] = $1
   next
}
{
   $2 = arr[FNR]
} 1' converted_data filtered_content
```

Answer (score 6):

A quick way using `paste` and `cut` and [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

```
paste -d';' <(cut -d';' -f1 filtered_content.txt) converted_content.txt
```

---

As per @oguzismail's comment, a Process Substitution is not needed.

```
cut -d ';' -f1 filtered_content.txt | paste -d';' - converted_content.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `converted_data` at all, just use GNU awk (for `mktime()` and `gensub()`) on `filtered_content` alone:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$NF=mktime(gensub(/[-T:]/," ","g",$NF),1)} 1' filtered_content
ip-172-31-42324-162.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1624684050
ip-172-31-42324-162.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1634015250
ip-172-31-4234-163.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1614661650
ip-172-31-4234-163.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1622005650
```

Comment: Yep, we gave the OP. what he wants but this answer is what he really needs.

Answer (score 3):

Taking inspiration from Ed sir's answer, using only `gsub` function of `awk` along with `mktime` function, pleas try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(/-|T|:|Z$/," ",$NF);$NF=mktime($NF)} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                       ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=";"                 ##Setting FS and OFS as semi-colon here.
}
{
  gsub(/-|T|:|Z$/," ",$NF)   ##Globally substituting - T : Z(at last) with space in  last field.
  $NF=mktime($NF)            ##Using mktime function to save values into last field itself, changing it to epoch time basically.
}
1                            ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Ed said, there is no need for a temporary file. Here is one way to do it in one go with `date`, `paste` and `cut`:

```
paste -d ';' <(cut -d';' -f1 infile) <(cut -d';' -f2 infile | date -f - +%s)
```

Output:

```
ip-172-31-42324-162.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1624684050
ip-172-31-42324-162.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1634015250
ip-172-31-4234-163.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1614661650
ip-172-31-4234-163.sa-east-1.compute.internal;1622005650
```